# threepenny-gui: how to get text?

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

With 'set text' in Threepenny-gui you can, given an element and an string, set the text of that element:

```
Prelude Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Core> :t set
set :: ReadWriteAttr x i o -> i -> UI x -> UI x
Prelude Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Core> :t set text
set text :: String -> UI Element -> UI Element
```

The existence of a get functions makes me think it should be possible to get the text given an element.

```
Prelude Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Core> :t get
get :: ReadWriteAttr x i o -> x -> UI o
Prelude Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Core> :t text
text :: WriteAttr Element String
Prelude Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Core> :t get text
get text :: Element -> UI ()
```

However, the return type of 'get text' is not what I expect. How do I recover the original String from an element?

Comment: that's a bit unidiomatic (I have to search a bit - right now I don't know if there is even something to do this in there) - normaly you define your inputs as behaviours and work with them (you can find an easy example here: https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/threepenny-gui/blob/master/samples/CurrencyConverter.hs)

Comment: based on the hackage-docs there is right now no way to get it out-of-the-box. as you saw yourself `text` is a `WriteAttr` and those *return* unit per definition (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.4.2.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#t:WriteAttr) - maybe you can try and create your own reader-attribut using [mkReaderAttr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.4.2.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#v:mkReadAttr) - see: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.4.2.0/docs/src/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#text

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the problem is that the text value of an element includes all its subelements as HTML code. I recommend to use `value` instead, which works for input fields.

The `ReadAttr` and `WriteAttr` are implemented in terms of `ReadWriteAttr` to avoid overloading. As the types indicate, `get` doesn't do anything useful for `WriteAttr` and `set` doesn't do anything useful for `ReadAttr`, though.